# Couchbase N1QL queries on server

Tags: couchbase

I used the [online](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#1) N1QL tutorial to practices writing queries. Now that I have a couchbase server of my own, I want to query my own data.

#### My questions is

Where in the Couchbase server can I write my queries?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Remember that N1Q1 is still in Beta.

The way it works is that you have to run Couchbase Query Server (aka CBQ). It runs in a default port 8093 (see [N1QL](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-query-language-0.1/)) 
The query server will connect to the specified Couchbase instance/cluster.
e.g.

```
cbq-engine -couchbase <CB-location>
```

Once CB Query Engine up and running you can run command line client and in a command prompt can issue your N1QL statements, e.g.:

```
cbq -engine http://your-cb-host:8093/

cbq> SELECT 'Hello World' AS Greeting
{
    "resultset": [
        {
            "Greeting": "Hello World"
        }
    ],
    "info": [
        {
            "caller": "http_response:160",
            "code": 100,
            "key": "total_rows",
            "message": "1"
        },
        {
            "caller": "http_response:162",
            "code": 101,
            "key": "total_elapsed_time",
            "message": "4.0002ms"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: where to write that please? i tried writing your code in the web page that I got when opening the starttutorial.bat but I keep getting error message

Comment: In command line client called "cbq". In a command prompt can issue your N1QL statements. I gave an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

N1QL is released and available as part of Couchbase Server.
Please download Couchbase Server 4.1 
http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads

Learn more at: http://www.couchbase.com/n1ql

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, there is a new developer preview of N1QL out now (http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/n1ql-dp3/n1ql-intro.html) and the way to connect to a Couchbase cluster has changed from the answer given by user1697575; it's now:

```
cbq-engine -datastore <CB-location>
```

The Couchbase query engine can also serve N1QL queries from a file system, and there is a file system included in the download that can be queried:

```
cbq-engine -datastore=dir:./data
```