# Run query on couchbase data imported using sqoop and hadoop connector

Tags: hadoop, couchbase, sqoop

I am using sqoop with hadoop couchbase connector to import some data from couchbase to hdfs.

As stated in 
http://docs.couchbase.com/hadoop-plugin-1.1/#limitations
querying is not supported for couchbase.

I want a solution to run query using the hadoop connector.

**For ex:**
I have 2 documents in db as follows:

{'doctype':'a'}

and

{'doctype':'b'}

I need to get only the docs which belong to docType=a.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify, "run query using the hadoop connector" - you want to select data from hdfs or from couchbase?

Comment: I want to select data from HDFS. Used sqoop+ couchbase hadoop connector and all the data from the bucket appears on the HDFS. I need some specific data only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select data from Couchbase, you don't need hadoop connector...you can just use couchbase view that filters on doc.doctype=='a'
See [couchbase views documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#views-and-indexes)

On other hand, I recommend using new [N1QL query](http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp3/) functionality from Couchbase. It is quite flexible query language (similar to SQL), see online [N1QL tutorial](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial).

**Note:** If you look at compatibility for N1QL to run it has v2.2 and higher, see [N1QL Compatibility](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-query-language-0.1/#compatibility)  You will need to deploy Couchbase N1QL Query server and point to your existing CB v2.2 cluster. see: [Couchbase N1QL queries on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620506/couchbase-n1ql-queries-on-server)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as stated in my question I need specific data from couchbase satisfying some condition which has to be imported to HDFS using the hadoop connector.                              Sqoop provides 'query' option but thats for RDBMS only and not for couchbase. I need a 'query' equivalent for Couchbase.             I dont think there is one.                                                  We might have to first import from couchbase to HDFS in text format and then run a PIG script or HIVE query and put the resulting back on the database. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Now its much clearer what you want to do. Try looking at latest Couchbase v3 N1QL (http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial). It offers query capability and perhaps there are plans to integrate N1QL with Sqoop's query framework. Seems like a natural fit.

Comment: That's great. Thank you. But I am restricted to be using Couchbase v 2.2. Hence I am working on PIG script for my current requirement. But anyways this is good to know.

Comment: Perfect. If you look at compatibility for N1QL to run it has v2.2 and higher: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-query-language-0.1/#compatibility You will need to deploy Couchbase N1QL Query server and point to your existing CB v2.2 cluster. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620506/couchbase-n1ql-queries-on-server

Comment: Can you please add your above findings on N1QL as an answer. I can accept it and it can help some one else who face the above doubt.

Comment: Just came through another plugin Couchdoop whose import function uses views to fetch data.     RESOURCES FOR THE SAME:    https://github.com/Avira/couchdoop                                                                                             http://www.slideshare.net/calinburloiu/couchdoop-connecting-hadoop-with-couchbase

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting another alternative for Sqoop for the above requirement called '**Couchdoop**'.

Couchdoop uses views to fetch data from Couchbase. Hence we can write a query as per our need and use Couchdoop to hit the view and fetch data.

https://github.com/Avira/couchdoop

Worked for me.